# How were the wounded in the Imperial army treated?

Tags: star-wars

The Imperial army of the Star Wars universe comprises thousands, millions (or even billions) of personnel. Let's assume one of the many Stormtroopers are injured in combat, **what is available to them in order to treat their wounds?**

For example, Steve the Stormtrooper has been *partially* decapitated by some rebel scum. Would Steve be able to go to a [aid station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aid_station#Military_operations), or even a [casualty clearing station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casualty_Clearing_Station) or [field hospital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_hospital) according to the state of his injuries?

**How are wounded treated in the Imperial army?**

Comment: Taken out behind the chemical sheds and put out of their misery, I expect.

Comment: "Partially decapitated" - trying not to visualize...

Comment: @OrganicMarble would you prefer for me to just say that he was "mildly mauled by some wookies"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Millions" of [2-1B-series medical droids](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/2-1B-series_medical_droid#Imperial_Era) were in the service of the Empire, as part of their [medic forces](https://www.starwars.com/databank/imperial-medics). Said medics were said to tend to soldiers in a variety of contexts.

> Imperial medics tend to soldiers on the battlefield and behind the front lines, with their duties encompassing everything from triage to preventive medicine. Medics benefit from the assistance of droids as well as the latest Imperial technology, utilizing equipment such as pain-relieving gas and antiseptic field projectors. The Empire interprets the galaxy’s ancient medical oaths as only applying to one’s own species, and allows its medics to bear arms in combat.

[image]

These medics served in [Imperial Mobile Surgical Units](https://www.starwars.com/databank/imperial-mobile-surgical-unit), where they treated a variety of conditions both dramatic and mundane.

> These collapsible shelters serve as a combination of doctor’s office and operating room for Imperial medics and droids. On Mimban, maladies include dehydration, microbial infections and “trench foot,” as well as the usual perils of battle.

[image]

We also have some examples of military personal receiving medical assistance. Medics [saved](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Truest_Duty) General Veers' life after he nearly died in the Battle of Hoth.  Captain Valance [received intense cybernetic enhancement](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Target_Vader_5) after barely surviving an explosion. We don't have as many stories about foot soldiers receiving medical assistance, but there also tend to be fewer stories from their perspective.

Comment: We need a Star Wars MASH cross-over series.

Comment: @Max I would watch that :D